# nested if loop in for loop to find if there is any change in file size and produce an html output of the same using bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, awk, sendmail

I want to check if there is any change in the file size in a dir ,here am going to compare the word count of older files with newer files for example older files would be like file.txt and newer files would be like file1.txt. And am doing `fgrep -vf file.txt file1.txt 
to get the difference between them and am making it to an html output to mail me. But this nested condition doesn't work any suggestions please.

```
for g in *1.txt;
do
if 
[ "wc -l < "$g"" != "wc -l "${g%1.txt}.txt"" ];
then 
awk '
BEGIN{
    print "Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\ntable,th,td\n{\nborder:1px solid black;\nborder-collapse:collapse;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<Body>\n<table> "
    } 
    {print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
END{
    print "\n</table>\n</Body>\n</html>\n"
    }' fgrep -vf "log.txt" "log1.txt" | sendmail -t "difference" hifi@example.com
fi
done
cat "${g%1.txt}.txt" > "$g"
```

Answer (score 0):

first if should be something like this

```
if [ `wc -l $g` -nq `wc -l $oldfile` ]
```

Comment: Why it should be like that both `!=` and `-nq` means the same right !!

Comment: @user2970582 becsuse == != is related to binary or string operations wile -eq and -nq for others such as integer